# how to return represent binary 1 and 0 using BitArray in python

Tags: python, binary, return, return-value, bitarray

i have audio file and i was represent the file with 1 and 0 using bitarray. but i want to get the result. when i return the variable, the result i got is not same as the text file was made. so how to return the result?

here's my code:

```
def readbinary(audio):
    # audio have my location file
    b=BitArray(bytes=open(audio,'rb').read())

    # Store result
    with open('txt/'+'binary.txt', 'w') as file1: 
        file1.write(b.bin) #the result from text file : 000000000000000000000000000110000110011001110100011110010111000001100100011000010111001101101000000000000000000000000000000000000110100101110011011011110011011001101101011100000011010000110001000000000000000000000010011000000110110101101111011011110111011000000000000000000000000001101100011011

    return b # the result from return : 0x0000001866747970646173680000000069736f366d703431000002606d6f6f760000006c6d76686400000000dea15aa0dea15aa00000a
```

i need the result 000000000000000000000000000110000110011001110100011110010111000001100100011000010111001101101000000000000000000000000000000000000110100101110011011011110011011001101101011100000011010000110001000000000000000000000010011000000110110101101111011011110111011000000000000000000000000001101100011011 to next stage

Comment: A string representation of a BitArray is done in hexadecimal, base 16, `0x...`. If you're printing the value that's what you're going to see. The `bin` property specifically represents the value in binary. Keep in mind these are just the string representations. The actual value is the same.

Comment: Also, an audio file is a data structure with a lot of information including things like sample rate, length, and audio signal data. When you read the file like this you're reading the entire structure as a series of bits. What these bits mean is entirely dependent on how you interpret them.

Comment: i just want to hide data to the audio using LSB steganography @MYousefi

Comment: Do you have to use BitArray?

Comment: yes, because i need to insert the result of modulation from spread spectrum. the modulation was binary 1 and 0. so if i want to input the result to audio, i need to change the audio to binary 1 and 0 too @MYousefi

Comment: You have loaded the binary data into the `b` object. All you have to do is manipulate  the data for the stenography. Don't worry how it displays.

Comment: ah i see, can you help me to do it in lsb method? @MYousefi

Comment: Assuming you are using `bitstring.BitArray`. Get message `msg` and audio data `audio` in `BitArray` objects. Loop over the message and for every value in `msg` use the `audio.overwrite` to replace the value at `8*msg_position` with the value from `msg`.